# Windows 7 Firewall Blocking FTP Server

Tags: windows-7, windows-firewall, ftp

Everything else is configured. When I turn the firewall off, it connects. When I turn it on, it doesn't. I've added inbound and outbound rules, opening port 21 for all programs and services, but it's not good enough. Why??

Comment: It looks like this has been answered over on ServerFault already. - http://serverfault.com/questions/78937/active-ftp-client-blocked-by-windows-firewall-on-windows-7

Answer (score 3):

FTP uses 2 channels for communication, ftp-data (20) and the ftp control channel (21). Depending on how you have it configured, active or passive, it will require a different configuration.

Windows makes things easier due to the fact that you can allow certain executables instead of specific ports. You can choose to allow the FTP server executable, or put the server into passive mode and allow ports 20 and 21.

Comment: The server is running as a service. I've now opened 20-21, but nothing. What's this about passive mode? I'm using zFTPserver.

Comment: Ok, now I've made it as open as possible, allowing any protocol on any port for the service, on both the inbound and outbound rules. It still won't work!

Comment: @xichael: don't forget you might have to open both TCP and UDP connections for those ports.

Comment: Both TCP and UDP were opened... I never did end up getting the Windows 7 firewall to work (even after reinstalling Windows) so I went with Comodo Firewall instead, and haven't had any issues.

Comment: I have the same problem - I can't get the firewall to allow incoming FTP; if I disable the firewall FTP works fine.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd421710(v=ws.10).aspx) is where the answer lies. Step 2 has a corresponding rule in Windows Firewall Advanced Settings (which you might tweak further), but I cannot find the rule for step 3 there.